# How do I prevent certain kinds of analyzer leak reports?

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks, clang-static-analyzer

I am wrapping a certain C API in Objective-C. I have a convenience method that takes some `CFTypeRef` from the procedural API and returns a wrapping object from the OOP API. This object keeps the passed `CFTypeRef` and releases it upon its own deallocation. The convenience method looks like this:

```
+ (id) wrapFoo: (CFTypeRef) foo;
```

I have a lot of methods that simply get some `CFTypeRef` and return the wrapping object:

```
- (id) doSomething {
    CFTypeRef foo = CFCreateSomeObject();
    id wrapper = [WrappingClass wrapFoo:foo];
    CFRelease(foo);
    return wrapper;
}
```

This is a bit clumsy, so that I came up with another convenience method:

```
+ (id) wrapNonRetainedFoo: (CFTypeRef) foo {
    id wrapper = [self wrapFoo:foo]; // CFRetains foo
    CFRelease(foo);
    return wrapper;
}
```

Now I can rewrite the `doSomething` method like this:

```
- (id) doSomething {
    return [WrappingClass wrapNonRetainedFoo:CFCreateSomeObject()]; // XXX
}
```

I like this. I’m not really proud of the `wrapNonRetainedFoo` method, but it’s not a part of the public interface of the package and saves me several lines of boilerplate code in several methods.

The downside is that the static analyzer flags the `XXX` line as a potential leak. What can I do better? I tried to toy with the `cf_consumed` argument attribute to let the analyzer know that I’m releasing the object later, but it does not seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) AFAIK cf_consumed is still not supported in versions of analyzer Apple uses.

2) I've noticed that if you make `wrapNonRetainedFoo` instance method warning will mysteriously disappear. But since `wrap...` is better to be a class method this is of no use to us.

3) Only solution I can think of is this ugly macro (not for production, just as proof of concept):

```
#define WRAP_CFTYPE(klass, valExpr) ({ CFTypeRef val = valExpr; id result = [klass wrap:val]; CFRelease(val); result; })
```

Usage:

```
WrappingClass *wrapper = WRAP_CFTYPE(WrappingClass, CFArrayCreate(NULL, NULL, 0, NULL))
```

Comment: For future reference, Xcode now seems to support the `CF_CONSUMED` macro. At least it appears to work in my 4.5 preview installation and makes the analyzer warning go away.